# Sed and grep in multiple files

Tags: linux, unix, sed, grep

I want to use "sed" and "grep" to search and replace in multiples files, excluding some directories.
I run this command:

```bash
$ grep -RnI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} 'chaine1' /projets/ | sed -i 's/chaine1/chaine2/'
```

I get this message:

> sed: pas de fichier d'entrée

I also tried with these two commands:

```bash
$ grep -RnI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} 'chaine1' . | xargs -0 sed -i 's/chaine2/chaine2/'
```

```bash
$ grep -RnI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} 'chaine2' . -exec sed -i 's/chaine1/chaine2/g' {} \;
```

But,it doesn't work!!

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `grep` command did not return file paths.

Comment: Unrelated but you're curious `sed: pas de fichier d'entrée` means `sed: no input file`.

Comment: @Darkman, Thanks for translation. Then the reason is that `sed -i` does not read from `stdin`. We need to pass a file path to it through `xargs`.

Comment: @ILS I'm not sure if the `--exclude-dir={...}` is a right syntax. I think OP want to exclude multiple directories. I might be wrong.

Comment: @Darkman, you're right and `{...}` is a right GLOB syntax.

Comment: Don't use `grep` (**G/RE/P**) to **find** files, use `find`. Your life will become a whole lot simpler. As written your grep command is just a big pile of mush trying to both **find** the files and **g/re/p** within the files. The GNU folks really messed up by adding the ability to find files onto `grep` - what's next, adding the ability to find files into `sed` or the ability to `sort` into `grep`?

Comment: @ed, that makes sense. I benefit a lot! A little question, is there a way to skip some directories using `find`?

Comment: Got it, `-prune` prevents it from descending into directories. But knittl's solution and mine give the different file paths. I need to dig into `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `find` with `-exec`. Don't bother running grep, sed will only change lines containing your pattern anyway.

```
find \( -name node_modules -o -name install -o -name build \) -prune \
  -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/chaine1/chaine2/' {} +
```

Comment: You can change `find ... -exec ... {} +` with `find ... -printf0 | xargs -0 sed -s -i ... ` for portability

Comment: @CervEd hmmm… I thought `-exec` was specified by POSIX, but `-print0` is not part of POSIX. Which would make `find -print0` less portable than using exec? Or are you referring to the `+` part specifically?

Comment: @CervEd https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/find.html lists `-exec {} +` as being POSIX, but does not include `-print0`, so I'm not sure what you meant with your comment. `find -print0 | xargs -0` is _less_ portable than `-exec {} +`.

Comment: I may be wrong but it was my impression that `exec ... {} +` was less portable than `print0  | args -0`. If it's POSIX and it works then its prefered

Answer (score 1):

First, the direct outputs of `grep` command are not file paths. They look like this `{file_path}:{line_no}:{content}`. So the first thing you need to do is to extract file paths. We can do this use `cut` command or use `-l` option of `grep`.

```bash
# This will print {file_path}
$ echo {file_path}:{line_no}:{content} | cut -f 1 -d ":"

# This is a better solution, because it only prints each file once even though
# the grep pattern appears at many lines of a file.
$ grep -RlI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} "chaine1" /projets/
```

Second, `sed -i` does not read from `stdin`. We can use `xargs` to read each file path from `stdin` and then pass it to `sed` as its argument. You have already done this.

The complete command like this:

```bash
$ grep -RlI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} "chaine1" /projets/ | xargs -i sed -i 's/chaine1/chaine2/' {}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @EdMorton's comment, I dig into `find`. My previous solutions will dig into files not in exclusive directories once by `grep`, and then process files containing pattern string for another time by `sed`. However, we can first use `find` to filter files according to their path names, and then use `sed` to process files only once.

My `find` solution is almost the same as @knittl's, but with bug fixed. Besides, I try to explain why it gets the **similar** results with `grep`. Because I still not find how to skip binary files like `-I` option of `grep`.

```bash
$ find \( \( -name node_modules -o -name install -o -name build \) -prune -type f \
          -o -type f \) -exec echo {} +
```

or

```bash
find \( \( -name node_modules -o -name install -o -name build \) -prune \
         -o -type f \) -type f -exec echo {} +
```

`\( -name pat1 -o -name pat2 \)` gives paths matching pat1 or pat2 (include files and directories), where `-o` means logical or. `-prune` ignores a directory and the files under it. They combine to achieve similar function with `exclude-dir` in `grep`.

`-type f` gives paths of regular files.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to try

```
$ sed -i 's/chaine1/chaine2/' $(grep -RnI --exclude-dir={node_modules,install,build} 'chaine1' /projets/)
```

Please tell me if it works for you.